# C++ OpenGL Project Setup using GLEW, assimp, SDL2 and CMake with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I've done a whole tutorial about making a 3D Rendering Engine in OpenGL with Java and lwjgl and the guy who made the tutorial also wrote the engine in C++

To increase my knowledge about programming I wanted to take a look at the C++ version too. Also I believe (and I might be totally wrong) that I'm actually able to do a lot more with C++ than with java. The main problem I have is that I cannot get the engine running despite the included instructions and I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

this is the engine i want to setup: https://github.com/BennyQBD/3DEngineCpp

I want to use CodeBlocks for this project since it was recommended and unlike Visual Studio it is free.. I also already downloaded glew, assimp and sdl and I installed CMake which are needed for this to run. Now I have to put that together according to this instruction here:

````
###Windows/MinGW###
- Make sure CMake is both installed and added to the system PATH.
- Open a Terminal and run:
```Shell 
# install dependencies
# Install GLEW in %PROGRAMFILES%/GLEW or SET %GLEW_ROOT_DIR% to where GLEW is on your machine (Example: D:\PATH_TO_GLEW)
# Install SDL2 in %PROGRAMFILES%/SDL2 or SET %SDL2_ROOT_DIR% to where SDL2 is on your machine (Example: D:\PATH_TO_SDL2)
# Install ASSIMP in %PROGRAMFILES%/ASSIMP or SET %ASSIMP_ROOT_DIR% to where ASSIMP is on your machine (Example: D:\PATH_TO_ASSIMP)
cd build
# REPLACE "Visual Studio 12" with your preferred build toolchain (Maybe you want "Codeblocks - MinGW Makefiles")
# BTW VS 10 is VS 2010, VS 11 is VS 2012 and VS 12 is VS 2013, BLAME MicroSoft for the naming! LOL! 
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../
# open the generated SLN file (or cbp file if using CodeBlocks) and build!
```
- Copy the DLLs in /lib/_bin/ to /build/Debug/ and /build/Release/
- In Visual Studio, set the Startup project to 3DEngineCpp
- Move the res folder into the build folder
- Run
````

Major problem is, since I've only done java coding in eclipse I'm a bit confused..

What does he mean by "Open a Terminal and run: '''Shell" ?? and how am I supposed to install glew, sdl2 and assimp? what's cd build? and why do I need CMake, it isn't really mentioned what it does..?

Maybe someone can elaborate (step by step if possible) what I need to do in order to get this running, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees my steps will work flawlessly as external dependencies in C++ is still very painful to deal with for me, but I'll give you some leads and hope you make some progress. Also, I've never used Code::Blocks, so I'm not sure if Visual Studio projects are compatible with it. This is the only way I know how to do things on Windows.

First, you'll need to install CMake. CMake is a utility that generates project files so that the project can be easily compiled on certain platforms. It generates Visual Studio project files on Windows, which will allow you to open the project in Visual Studio, and compile them from there.

In order to build the project, you'll have to sort out its dependencies first.

---

GLEW:

1. Download GLEW's [sources](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and extract everything. It comes with Visual Studio project files
2. Open up Visual Studio with Administrator permissions
3. Open up GLEW's project
4. Build everything
5. Run the `install` "project" to get Visual Studio to install GLEW

---

Assimp:

1. Download Assimp's [source](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases) from GitHub
2. Extract the project root directory somewhere. The root directory is the directory where `CMakeLists.txt` is in
3. Open CMake's GUI utility
4. Click Browse Source, and select that directory
5. Select an output directory by clicking Browse Build
6. Click Configure, when that's done click Generate. This will generate a Visual Studio project file for you
7. Open project with Visual Studio, build everything. Run `install` like you did before to install Assimp

---

SDL2: SDL's sources come with Visual Studio project files, so you can repeat the steps for GLEW to install it.

---

Now you can finally start attempting to get the engine to work. No guarantees that it'll work, but I'd try the same thing I suggested for Assimp as they're both CMake projects. Once the project files are generated, you can open it up in Visual Studio. Except this time, you won't really be installing it. You can modify the sources and run it like you would any other C++ project.